# Why in Spring JUnit test a new ApplicationContext is initialized and created for each test method?

Tags: java, spring, junit, applicationcontext, spring-test

I am studying unit test in Spring and I have the following doubt.

Why a new ApplicationContext is initialized and created for each test method?

Why Spring need a new ApplicationContext for each test method and not reuse a same ApplicationContext created before perfome any method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There is no need to create new `ApplicationContext` every time.
- You have to do is to use the same locations attribute in your test classes:

  ```
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-context.xml")
  ```
- Spring caches application contexts by locations attribute so if the same locations appears for the second time, Spring uses the same context rather than creating a new one.
- You can refer to the link: [NoBlogDefFound: Speeding up Spring integration tests](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2010/12/speeding-up-spring-integration-tests.html).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you set up your test. If you use `@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `@ContextConfiguration`, then Spring will cache existing `ApplicationContext`s and reuse them.

You can mark a context as dirty to prevent this reuse.

If you create your own `ApplicationContext`, then you need to implement your own reuse/caching strategy.